# CSS: divs not stacking

Tags: css, pocketgrid

I am using [Pocketgrid](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/) to make the website responsive.

The way that pocketgrid works is that the "thirty-block" class should stack on top of "seventy-block" class, when I reduce the size of my browser to that of a mobile device. But this isn't happening. Where am I going wrong?

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="wrapper block-group">

  <div class="top-bar block">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="header block-group">
    <div class="focus-area block-group">
      <div class="logo thirty-block block">
        <p><span class="text-logo">LoremLOGO</span></p>
        <p><span class = "tagline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>
      </div>    
      <div class="seventy-block block">
      <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-End focus-area -->
  </div> <!-End header-->

</div> <!-End wrapper-->
```

This is what my CSS looks like:

```
/*! PocketGrid 1.1.0
* Copyright 2013 Arnaud Leray
* MIT License
*/
/* Border-box-sizing */
.block-group, .block, .block-group:after, .block:after, .block-group:before, .block:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Clearfix */
.block-group {
  *zoom: 1;
}
.block-group:before, .block-group:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  line-height: 0;
}
.block-group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.block-group {
  /* ul/li compatibility */
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Nested grid */
.block-group > .block-group {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

/* Default block */
.block {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.header{
  width: 100%;
}

.focus-area {
  width: 100%;
}

.thirty-block {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}
.seventy-block {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: There are no media queries in the above css for your blocks?

Comment: Thanks pete for pointing out. I looked though the example provided by the pocketgrid -> http://jsfiddle.net/Ltydw83L/ Now it works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've already sorted it but just for further and future help to anyone else having a similar issue with this or media queries here's an example showing a similar navigation, with a mobile media query change.

http://jsfiddle.net/vmggcv0g/

Using the following query to change the list item state on mobiles (when the screen is less than 480px):

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)
```

along with the box-sizing property to allow padding and borders on the list items (with out this property the item width would exceed the 100% width as it will include the 1px border):

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
```

Here's a great css-tricks article explaining the box-sizing property and css box model further:

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

I'm ignoring default PocketGrid rules and consider only your custom code:

the following rules are unuseful because PocketGrid has a [Mobile First approach](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/docs/#mobile-layout), so this is default behaviour.

```
.header{
  width: 100%;
}

.focus-area {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Considering that you would 30-70 proportions only above mobile breakpoints, you should include them in a specific media-query like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px)
{
  .thirty-block {
     width: 30%;
     background-color: green;
  }
  .seventy-block {
     width: 70%;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

On screens below 480px wide, every item is stacked, over it, you'll have 30-70 cols side-by-side